# Given a bounded sequence in $L^1([a,b])$, is $(t\mapsto \int_a^t f_n \,\mathrm d\lambda)_n$ equicontinuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

We are given a bounded sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in $L^1([a,b])$.
This means there is some $M>0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $\int_{[a,b]} |f_n|\,\mathrm d\lambda \leq M$.
I wonder whether the corresponding sequence $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of integrals
$$F_n : [a,b]\to \mathbb R,\quad t\mapsto \int_a^t f_n \,\mathrm d\lambda$$
is *equicontinuous* at all $x\in [a,b]$,
i.e. for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta> 0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $y\in [a,b]$ with $|y-x|<\delta$ we have $|F_n(x)-F_n(y)| < \varepsilon$.

**Edit:** Clarifcation. I don't assume the functions $f_n$ to be bounded in the sense that there is some $M$ with $f_n(t)\leq M$ for all $t\in [a,b]$.
Instead, I assume that all $f_n$ are bounded in the metric space $(L^1([a,b]), \lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^1})$ as explained above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n - n^2x & \text{if} & x \le \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then obviously $$\|f_n\|_{L_1} = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} n -n^2x dx = 1 - n^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}xdx = 1-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} $$ so $\{f_n\}_n$ is bounded in $L_1([0,1])$. However, looking at $x=0$, and taking $y \in (0,1)$ we have $$ |F_n(0) - F_n(y)| = \int_0^y n - n^2x dx = ny - \frac{n^2y^2}{2}$$
At $y = y(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ you get $|F_n(0)-F_n(y)| = \frac{1}{2}$. So it is true that for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ there is no $\delta > 0$ (because sequence $y(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$) such that for all $n$ and all $y < \delta$ you have $|F_n(0)-F_n(y)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: In fact it can be even easier. Just consider $f_n(x) = n$ for $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $0$ otherwise. The same argument holds then. I've missed the fact that you do not assume continuity.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to dig deeper into it. The reason I came up with such a counterexample was that the condition of $\{F_n\}$ being equicontinuous is very similar (not sure, but might be even equivalent due to regularity of Lebesgue measure) to "uniform integrability" of $\{f_n\}$ and it is known that merely boundedness of $\{f_n\}$ in $L_1$ is not enough to ensure uniform integrability (via the same standard counterexample)

Comment: Thanks for the simple counter example and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Since $|F_n(x) - F_n(y)| = | \int_x^y (f_n)| \leq \int_x^y | f_n| \leq (b-a) M,$ yes.

Comment: I need to prove that  $|F_n(x)-F_n(y)| < \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary and might be smaller than $(b-a) M$.

Comment: Sorry, replace $b-a$ by $\delta.$

Comment: Then, how is $\int_x^y |f_n| \leq \delta \cdot M$? Maybe you misunderstood my question; the sequence $f_n$ is bounded in $L^1([a,b])$, the functions $f_n$ might not be bounded in a uniform sense...

Comment: In $L_1$ or in $L_2?$

Comment: They are bounded in $L^1$  :)

Answer (score 0):

YES.

If $g_n(x)=\int_a^x f_n(t)\,dt$ and $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|=M$, then
$$
|g_n(x)-g_n(y)|=\left|\int_{[x,y]}f(t)\,dt\right|\le 
\int_{[x,y]}|f(t)|dt\le M|x-y|.
$$
Hence, for every $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
|x-y|<\delta=\varepsilon/M\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
|g_n(x)-g_n(y)|<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: I do not assume $f_n$ to be bounded in the sense that $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)| < \infty$. Instead I assume, that the $L^1$ norm of $f_n$ is bounded, i.e. $\int |f_n| \,\mathrm d \lambda \leq M <\infty$ for some $M > 0$