# Is the integral operator $I: L^1([0,1])\to L^1([0,1]), f\mapsto (x\mapsto \int_0^x f \,\mathrm d\lambda)$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces, compact-operators, arzela-ascoli

Is the integral operator $I: L^1([0,1])\to L^1([0,1]), f\mapsto (x\mapsto \int_0^x f \,\mathrm d\lambda)$ compact?

For $I: L^p([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ with $p\in (1,\infty]$ this can be shown quite easily using Hölder's inequality and the compactness criterion in the Arzelà-Ascoli-Theorem (see also the first example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Further_examples)).

I wonder whether the statement holds also for $p=1$.
However, we cannot just apply Arzelà-Ascoli here, because a bounded sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in $(L^1([0,1]), \lVert\cdot\rVert_{L^1})$ is not necessarily equicontinuous (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343296/given-a-bounded-sequence-in-l1a-b-is-t-mapsto-int-at-f-n-mathrm-d/4343310#4343310)).
Moreover, $I: L^1([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ is not compact as discussed in the comments.

**Edit:** As answered in the comments, $I: L^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ is not compact. Therefore, I removed this aspect of the question.

Comment: You should clarify what you meant by elementary: explain what your background is for example.

Comment: I simply do not have a large foundation of functional analysis; I haven't attended any course nor have I read a complete functional analysis book.

Comment: How do you define a compact operator then?

Comment: A compact operator is a linear operator that maps bounded sets in one metric space to relatively compact sets in the other metric space.

Comment: Ok. Well, a quick search on Volterra operator gives me this: https://johnthickstun.com/docs/volterra.pdf

Comment: Ok, this PDF shows, that $I$ is not compact from $L^1([0,1])$ to $C([0,1])$, but does this also hold for $I: L^1([0,1])\to L^1([0,1])$ (or is this obvious by any means?)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the operator is compact from $L^1$ to $L^1$. This follows from a duality argument:

It can be easily checked that the dual operator $I': L^\infty([0,1]) \to L^\infty([0,1])$ is given by
$$
  (I'g)(x) = \int_x^1 g \; d\lambda \quad \text{for } x \in [0,1]
$$
for all $g \in L^\infty([0,1])$, so $I': L^\infty \to L^\infty$ is compact by the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem. But a bounded linear operator is compact if and only if its dual operator is compact, so $I: L^1 \to L^1$ is compact, too.